# Owin unauthorized request not signing out user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin

In my ASP MVC project i've implemented OWIN CookieAuthentication. All works well and good except for unauthorized requests.
For example, consider the flow:

1. User logs in
2. User hits the endpoint for which user is not authorized to access.

Restricted through:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "SomeRoleUserDontHaAssigned")]
public ActionResult SomeAction()...
```

When that happens user gets redirected to Account/Login route (which is ok) but he doesn't get logged off (which i would expect).

Is this expected behavior so that i should implement my own AuthorizeAttribute in which i should delete cookie manually (or call Account/SignOut)? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Why do you expect something like that? As a user I would be slightly pissed if I had to re-login every time I hit resource that I don't have access to. You can do it through custom AuthorizeAttribute, but should you?

Comment: i see your point. i should elaborate it a bit better: i agree completely with you from the users experience point of view. what i actually wanted to say is: if it already redirects to login page, then (and only then) i would expect to sign out user first because what is the point of logging in already logged user? isn't that really wierd? on the other hand, full proper solution would of course be to redirect to some custom 'Access denied' page. Btw, where is that set up?

Comment: I can't fully understand your question, how do you expect that the user should be logged off if he hit a restricted page? the only way the user would be logged of is either when the cookie dies or you sign out the user through the authentication manager (authenticationManager.SignOut)

Comment: well, i wouldn't expect him to be redirected to account/login either, in the first place. but SINCE they've chosen to do so my question is what was  intended idea about signing out - was that also something they wanted and i missed or they just left it as is? my expectance, by the book, would be to serve back 403 Forbidden Status Code and that's it. Then i would, eventually, intercept 403 and serve custom Unauthorized error page. But this redirection obviously steps into that process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to put this in an answer as it might not fit into a single comment.

First of all, lets go back to basics - HTTP status codes. There are two main codes that you are interested in when talking about authentication and authorization - 401 and 403.

From RFC 7235 spec:

**3.1.  401 Unauthorized (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-3.1)**

> The 401 (Unauthorized) status code indicates that the request has
> not    been applied because it lacks valid authentication credentials
> for    the target resource.

**6.5.3.  403 Forbidden (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.3)**

> The 403 (Forbidden) status code indicates that the server understood
> the request but refuses to authorize it.  A server that wishes to make public
> why the request has been forbidden can describe that reason in the response
> payload (if any).

In other words, 401 means that there is a problem with authentication (either user is not authenticated or is authenticated incorrectly). One can provide valid credentials and try again. At the same time, 403 means there are problems with permissions. Server knows who the user is but denies access - one should not try again with the same credentials.

OWIN CookieAuthentication just sits there and listens for 401 error code being returned. If it detects such code, response is replaced with redirect to login page maintaining return address.

Despite the name of AuthorizeAttribute, it actually generates 401 status code. https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/AuthorizeAttribute.cs#L155

Therefore, user is taken to login page.

If you want to change that, you might need to implement your own AuthorizeAttribute. Then you could check if user has already logged in and return 403 status. If the user hasn't logged in, just return 401.

Comment: thank you for your comment. that is exactly what i ended up doing for the same reason you mentioned: http specs. the problem seems to be in fact that AuthorizeAttribute interprets both as 401. Hard to understand the reasons behind it but i guess we have to live with it. Marking your answer because it brought full clarity to the topic.